# How do I adapt the WinRT JScript RDP sample to XAML?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winrt-xaml

The WinRT JScript sample "Remote Desktop app container client sample" runs the RDP activeX component. This sample is similar to the RDP App downloaded from Windows Store. The sample is contained in [MSDN Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples). As you can see from the code the JScript is doing ActiveX in a WinRT app!!! Does any one know how to adapt this sample to XAML ?

```
        createClientControl: function (desktopWidth, desktopHeight) {
        // Initialize RDP client control.
        // Create object element.
        var clientControlObject = document.createElement("object");

        // Register for ActiveX events.
        clientControlObject.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (e) {
            if (clientControlObject.readyState !== 4) {
                WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Error: ActiveX control readyState is not 4. ReadyState: " + clientControlObject.readyState, "sample", "error");
            }
        }, false);

        clientControlObject.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Error in loading the ActiveX control", "sample", "error");
        }, false);

        // Set object's classid to RDP client control's s CLSID.
        clientControlObject.classid = "CLSID:EAB16C5D-EED1-4E95-868B-0FBA1B42C092";

        clientControlObject.id = "clientControl";

        // Set object's height and width.
        clientControlObject.width = desktopWidth;
        clientControlObject.height = desktopHeight;

        // Add the element to  DOM.
        var clientControlRegion = document.getElementById("clientControlRegion");
        clientControlRegion.appendChild(clientControlObject);

        return clientControlObject;
    },
```

Comment: It is polite to mark the best/correct answer.

Comment: Just use JavaScript I created a test app, and it works fine :)
Don't forget to add needed capabilities in the app manifest!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to download the C# sample and see how they did it (instead of translating the JS version) http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples/file/60705/34/Windows%208%20app%20samples.zip

Comment: could you be more specific about the location of the C# sample. I downloaded the C# samples from the link you provided and  "Remote Desktop app container client sample" is not in the set of contained folders. Did not see any thing similar.

Comment: there is no C# sample, nether is the JavaScript sample which you should go for published.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974571.aspx) says that Remote Desktop Services in this context is designed for Javascript:

> **Developer audience**
>
> Remote Desktop Services objects for Windows Store apps are designed for use by Windows
>   Store apps using JavaScript.

As far as I know there is no C# sample available, which was probably your question.

Because XAML has nothing to do with the implementation of RDP.